# Why cant JPA/hibernate map to MySQL blob type?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I got the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in TestTable for column PAYLOAD. Found: blob, expected: tinyblob
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 60 more
```

The column hibernate is complaining about is declared as

```
private byte[]  messagePayload;

@Column(name="PAYLOAD")
public byte[] getMessagePayload() {
        return messagePayload;
}

public void setMessagePayload(byte[] messagePayload) {
 this.messagePayload = messagePayload;
}
```

The table in the MySQL table is declared as a BLOB type. Why doesnt Hibernate want to map to it and why does it insist that i use TINYBLOB?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try to set explicitly the type blob with **columnDefinition** attribute. Like this:

```
@Column(name="PAYLOAD",columnDefinition="blob")
```

Or use the @Lob annotation:

```
@Column(name="PAYLOAD")    
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
```

Comment: `columnDefinition` is not portable, later is standard. `type` is available in hibernate while it isn't in JPA.

Comment: I have done the second with EclipseLink and MySQL and can verify that it works as expected.

Comment: I have added comment for more information to the answer as OP has mentioned tags JPA/Hibernate, not about its working.

Comment: Where is your `@Lob` annotation coming from? The JPA one doesn't seem to have a `type` argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Column(columnDefinition="blob")
```

Did not work for me.
My specifications:
- JPA
- Hibernate
- MySQL

Solution:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table_name` CHANGE `my_column` `my_column` LONGBLOB default NULL;

public MyClass {
   @Lob
   @Column(length=100000)
   private byte[] myBlob;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this solution:

```
public class MySqlCustomDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect{

    public MySqlCustomDialect() {

        super();

        this.registerColumnType(-4, "blob");
        this.registerColumnType(-3, "blob");
        this.registerColumnType(-3, 16777215L, "blob");
        this.registerColumnType(-3, 65535L, "blob");
        this.registerColumnType(-3, 255L, "blob");
        this.registerColumnType(2004, "blob");

    }
}
```

This way, I've overridden the original value for ColumnType defined in MySqlDialect. It works only is BLOB is defined as column type in MySQL. I've experienced a side effect trying to alter column type to LONGBLOB, as expected:

[longblob (Types#LONGVARBINARY)], but expecting [blob (Types#BLOB)]

Just for previous re-configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Hello this works for me.

```
@Lob  
@Column(name = "CH_VAL_MODIFIEES")
private String valeurModifiee;
```

In my dataBase, I have a `CH_VAL_MODIFIEES` created with **LONGTEXT** DataType.