# How to use "like" predicate and "%" in JPA/Hibernate @NamedNativeQuery and Spring Data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I am currently trying to implement an @NamedNativeQuery for one of my entity classes. My project uses Spring data and I have two tables in my DB : Pizza and Town (origin of the pizza). The query itself consists in finding the pizza by providing a town name. So, finding whether the town.name contains the provided parameter (a part of the town name in our case). So naturally, I have something like this :

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "Pizza.findByTown",
    query = "select p.* from pizza p join town t on p.town_id = t.id on where t.name like '%?1%'",
    resultClass = Pizza.class
)
})
public class Pizza {
}
```

So in my PizzaRepository, I have added the following

```
public interface PizzaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pizza, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Pizza> {
    Pizza findByTown(final String townName)
```

It seems that the % does not work with the named query. Is there a work around for this ? Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

[EDIT] : I have added the annotated class Town

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Town")
public class Town {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "town_id")
    private String townId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "picture", nullable = false)
    private byte[] picture;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that findByTown will use the native query defined (Pizza.findByTown). What is the error, or the generated SQL ?

Comment: Do you really need a native query for this request. WIth JPQL/HQL it would be easier to use findByTownContaining : that would add directly your %

Comment: @willome I have to do it that way because the Town table was not part of the JPA model at the beginning (this table was added) so I tried to JPA-map it by adding the annotations (bottom-top approach). My attempt failed because the table contains a BLOB column and mapping this column with a "@Lob" caused an error : "found longblob, expected: blob" even though I am adding a columnDefinition with the "@Column" annotation. If I can just find a way to map the blob column db correctly then I can solve it. Any hint ?

Comment: Could you post your entity having this @Lob column (It could be a mapping error)

Comment: @willome I have edited the Town class for your information. The table definition in DB is a BLOB.

Comment: Well your entity seems fine. I think you could ask a new question for your @Lob problem ;)

Comment: Your @Lob problem is resolved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299015/why-cant-jpa-hibernate-map-to-mysql-blob-type

Comment: already tried this one ... does not work either

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

`select p.* from pizza p join town t on p.town_id = t.id on where t.name like :param_1"`

And then in code, can set parameter as below.

`query.setParameter("param_1", "%"+param_value+"%");`

Comment: but I can't set it that way since I am directly using Spring data as a way to set the query parameter (c.f : the findByTown method in PizzaRepository interface)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a native query for this request. WIth JPQL/HQL it would be easier to use `findByTownContaining` : that would add directly your %.
See Table 2.2. Supported keywords inside method names on spring data jpa documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: once again the problem is that the "@Lob" is giving me an error with this approach. It keeps sending me "expected longblob, found: blob" even though I use columndefinition. So I guess a mismatch in the type has to be fixed.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `my_table_name` CHANGE `my_column` `my_column` LONGBLOB default NULL; ?